# How to remove 0 value rows from the output

Tags: sql

i need to consider only rows with p qty is non-zero

i tried [P Qty] <> 0  and [P Qty] != 0 in where condition but it did not work

```
select ile.[Document No_],ile.[Source No_],ile.[Posting Date],
sum(ile.Quantity) as [P Qty],

sum([Cost Amount (Actual)]) as [P Cost]
from [X Limited$Item Ledger Entry] ile
left join [X Limited$Value Entry] ve
on ile.[Entry No_] = ve.[Item Ledger Entry No_] 
left join [X$Item] i
on i.No_ = ile.[Item No_]
left join 
 [X$Location] on ile.[Location Code]= [X$Location].[Code] 

where  ile.[Posting Date] between '2019-03-01' and '2019-03-31' and ile.[Order Type] =1 and ile.[Document No_]='RPOS/1819/03/1059' 
and ile.[Entry Type] =6 and  [X$Location].[Production Location]= 1 and ile.[Quantity]<>0

group by ile.[Document No_],ile.[Source No_],ile.[Posting Date]


) as P
on  P.[Document No_] = C.[Document No_] and P.[P Qty]!=0 
where P.[Document No_]='RPOS/1819/03/1059' and P.[P Qty] <> 0
```

Comment: Please proper format your query. Can't find in your query what is subquery for your `P` table, so can't see where's the column `P.[P Qty]`. Only saw `) as P`, no `(` available

Comment: " it did not work", meaning wrong result returned or you got an error? Also tag  your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I assume you use SQL Server as this code isnt valid ISO/ANSI SQL? As this bracket syntax is only SQL Server valid

Answer (score 0):

You can have HAVING clause after where clause

```
HAVING [P Qty] != 0;
```

Comment: how to select a single row  from the result obtained through max date